# How to change the filter chip icon

Tags: flutter

I am having some issue changing the icon in a Filter chip in Flutter.
I would like to add a "+" when displaying the widget. Then, if the user selects the chip, then change the icon to a checkmark.

As you can see from the first picture, the icon is changed to a "check", but there is a white checkmark underneath.

How can I remove this extra checkmark?

Code Snippet

```
FilterChip(
   avatar: selected.contains(ms.items[i].text)
      ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Palette.BLUE)
      : Icon(Icons.add, color: Palette.GREY),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
         side: BorderSide(
            color: Palette.BLUE,
         ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Palette.WHITE,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      label: Text(
          ms.items[i].text,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
               height: 1.4,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
               color: Palette.GREY,
           ),
      ),
```

Current Display

[image: Current Display 3]

Desired Display

[image: Desired Display 2]

Initial display

[image: Initial display 3]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `showCheckmark` to `false`. Also, change the border and text color according to the selection state.

```
FilterChip(
  showCheckmark: false,
  avatar: selected.contains(ms.items[i].text)
  ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Palette.BLUE)
  : Icon(Icons.add, color: Palette.GREY),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: selected.contains(ms.items[i].text)
      ? Palette.BLUE
      : Palette.GREY,
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Palette.WHITE,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  label: Text(
    ms.items[i].text,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16.0,
      height: 1.4,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      color: selected.contains(ms.items[i].text)
      ? Palette.BLUE
      : Palette.GREY,
    ),
  ),
  selectedColor: Palette.WHITE,
  onSelected: ...
```